# can chicken be thawed in the sun

Tags: food-safety

My mother-in-law put chicken on the counter to thaw for an hour then put the chicken directly into the sunlight still on the counter top! I've done a little Research but have found nothing that clearly states not to eat chicken thawed in the sun, only how to thaw chicken instead of how not to thaw chicken...any help is much needed I have children and don't want to chance them getting any food Bourne illnesses

Comment: Sunlight or not doesn't really matter, it's just the fact that you're doing it at room temperature - that means you're leaving it in the danger zone way too long.